# Source Control for Selenium Tests written in Java

Tags: intellij-idea, tfs, version-control

In my company, I have plans to introduce Web Automation using Selenium WebDriver and Cucumber JVM using Maven builds. 
Since the developers write their code in C#, they are all using TFS for source code repository and recommending the QA team also to use TFS to maintain my tests written in JAVA.

These are the questions I have got in my mind:

1. QA team will use IntelliJ IDE for writing Selenium tests in JAVA. Is IntelliJ compatible with TFS? Or is it a pain to configure it to work with TFS?
2. As we will move towards TDD very soon, we have to setup CI server as well. 
   Is it possible for me to run Selenium Tests triggered from TFS or do I need to use a separate CI server like Jenkins or Teamcity?
3. Does maven build work smoothly with TFS?
4. We have to adhere to stringent ISO guidelines for maintaining the source code. If I were to recommend source code repositories like github, can I ensure that the code is still secure? Is it difficult to setup the security in github?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your questions regarding TFS:

1. IntelliJ IDEA supports TFS up to TFS 2015. Check:

   - [Visual Studio Team Foundation Plugin for IntelliJ and Android Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/10/23/visual-studio-team-foundation-plugin-for-intellij-and-android-studio/)
   - [Using TFS Integration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/using-tfs-integration.html)
2. TFS supports CI build. After you've deployed a Windows build agent or an Xplat build agent, you are ready to define a CI build that compiles your Java app with Maven whenever your team checks in code.
3. Yes. Check:

   - [Build your Java app with Maven](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/get-started/java-maven)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Cece - MSFT